# Dropdown going to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=d0aVDl0LjI

The dropdown for the 'Games' tab is going all the way to the bottom of the page, instead of right under the tab.

Any ideas what is going on? I've looked at the css and I can't see any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the system *where* the list should be positioned absolutely.

The way to do that is to give `position: relative;` on the parent.

Change your css to include this as below:

```
li {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display:inline;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    line-height:40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Once you do, the drop-down shows in the right place vertically, but all the way to the left.  To fix that, simply add `left: 0;` to the ul subnav css:

```
.nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Finally, you'll want to style the subnav li / a elements to be display block, so they show up properly:

```
.nav ul ul li {
    float:none;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul li a {
    display: block;   
}
```